# Python - cannot unpack non-iterable int object when declaring variable

Tags: python

I get the following error "cannot unpack non-iterable int object" when attempting to run the following line of code.

```
numOf95Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf75Rows, numOfLess75Rows = 0
```

But when I specifically declare each variable, I do not get the error. Why is that?

```
numOf95Rows = 0
numOf85Rows = 0 
numOf85Rows = 0
numOf75Rows = 0 
numOfLess75Rows = 0
```

Comment: The error makes sense, as you are trying to assign a single value to 5 variables in the wrong way. To achieve what you want do this `numOf95Rows = numOf85Rows = numOf85Rows = numOf75Rows = numOfLess75Rows = 0`

Comment: Because `int` object is not an iterable. `Iterable` is the object that you can loop through (list, tuple, set,...). In your case you can use: `a,b,c = (0,0,0)`

Comment: The one-liner you're looking for: `numOf95Rows=numOf85Rows=numOf85Rows=numOf75Rows=numOfLess75Rows=0` the unpacking you were trying works as follows: eg `a,b=[0,0]`

Comment: Alternatively, `numOf95Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf75Rows, numOfLess75Rows = (0,)*5`. I'd rather stick to the 1 assignment per line though. And if many values, use a list or something similar. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error will be resolved by this

```
numOf95Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf85Rows, numOf75Rows, numOfLess75Rows = 0,0,0,0,0
```

In python when you are using any this kind of multi-assignment then the right hand side must be an `iterable` or same number of values as variabbles delimited by comma.

You are getting this error because there is only 1 variable which is integer and `non-iterable`, thats why it cannot un-pack the value like an `iterable` to assign the values.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks... totally forgot that. I greatly appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: my pleasure, would be great if u upvote/accept the solution if it helped @emie

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign same value to multiple variables than instead of using `,` use `=`

**Code**

```
numOf95Rows = numOf85Rows = numOf85Rows = numOf75Rows = numOfLess75Rows = 0
print(numOf95Rows)
```

**Output**

```
0
```

[Refer this doc for more information](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/assignment.html)